# sparklyr : Error in validate_java_version_line(master, version)

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) -- "Eggshell Igloo" Copyright (C) 2018
The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform:
x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
```

After running these commands:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
```

I got this message:

```
* Using Spark: 2.4.0
Error in validate_java_version_line(master, version) : 
  Java version detected but couldn't parse version from: openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
```

I've found this case https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/1922

But not sure if there is something concrete I could do (and how) to overcome this blocked situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spark doesn't support JDK > 8 at the moment. So the only thing you can do is to downgrade JDK.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Java 8. You can install one from https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/ (select Coretto 8 for Java 8).
2. Go to terminal & run R with proper `JAVA_HOME` env variable set:

```
JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` R
```

or if you want to launch RStudio:

```
JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` open /Applications/RStudio.app
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the exact same issue when upgrading JDK from 8 (on Ubuntu 16.04) to 11 (on Ubuntu 18.04). The chance is JDK 8 is still in your system, so you can downgrade easily with:

```
update-java-alternatives --list
sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Now `sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")` works.